# Cross origin resource sharing using Express and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, cross-domain

I am in the following situation. I want to apply cross origin resource sharing on express (node.js) and for this reason I am using cors. I have a statement of the form

```
app.use(cors());
```

before the statement

```
app.use(app.router);
```

on the app.js file (of course I am loading cors on the top part of the file). For the responses generated by the server I am using the following object:

```
var options = {
    "ETag"                         : "",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  : "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    "Content-Type"                 : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Transfer-Encoding"            : "chunked"
};
```

and then by iterating through the keys of this object I set the headers of every response.

I believe so far so good. Now, on the client side I am using ajax in order to say post a request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    accepts: "application/json",
    url: urlForPOST,
    data: JSON.stringify(theData),
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert("Received success: '" + JSON.stringify(data) + "' with ETag '" + jqXHR.getResponseHeader('ETag') + "'");
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Received error: '" + JSON.stringify(data) + "'\n Status: '" + textStatus + "'\n error thrown = '" + errorThrown + "'");
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    username: myData.username,
    password: myData.password
}).done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
}).fail(function() {
    alert( "error while posting" );
}).always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});
```

Now, I end up in the following strange situation. When the client and the server are running on the same machine and in the url I have written down "localhost" then I am able to post requests from the client (same machine). When I replace the "localhost" part of the address with the actual IP that the server has on the LAN then I can post requests from clients in other machines (and hence other IPs) but *not* from a client on the same machine where the server is actually running. In fact, in this case when I am using the client on the same machine I see in the server log the following:

```
OPTIONS /aRoute 204 1ms
POST /aRoute 401 2ms
```

and the client informs me that this is an unauthorized transaction. Well, first of all the username and the password that I am sending are for sure correct; so that is not the case.

Moreover, why does this OPTIONS appear there in the log in this case? When I am posting from clients running in other machines there is no such thing in the server log. In addition, this is not something that I would expect.

Concluding, can someone explain why this OPTIONS appears there in this case on the server log? Moreover, is there a way of writing down a cross origin ajax request that works both when I am using a client on the same machine as the server is running (clearly for debugging purposes), as well as when I am posting requests from different machines? There is at least one detail here that I am missing.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

---

I am editing the original post to mention this thing as well:
When I remove the requirement for the "cors" module and the relevant "app.use(cors());" statement, then I am able to intercept the incoming requests on the address using "app.options(...);" and print a console.log statement. In particular I am using the statement:

```
app.options(aRoute, function (request, response, next) {
    console.log("FOLLOWING ROUTE THROUGH OPTIONS");
    defs.SET_DEFAULT_JSON_HEADER(response);
    next();
});
```

where SET_DEFAULT_JSON_HEADER sets the headers according to the options that I listed above.

Comment: OPTIONS is a request that happens during a CORS request that makes it possible for a CORS request to happen. If an OPTIONS request isn't happening, then CORS isn't happening. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Ok, but then how can it be justified that I can actually post a request from a different machine when I am writing down the actual IP address of the server and I am not able to do so when I am using a client on the same machine? Plus, why, without changing anything in the code in both cases, do I see this OPTIONS part only in one of the cases (client on same machine) and not in the other one (client on a different machine)?

Comment: Please clarify. Different machine vs same machine has nothing to do with CORS. It's all about protocol/domain/subdomain/port.

Comment: OPTIONS is not actually a required part of CORS.  An OPTIONS/preflight is only sent for "non-simple" CORS requests.  For "simple" CORS requests, no OPTIONS/preflight is sent, the original request is sent, but the server must still acknowledge the Origin in order for the client to have access to the response.

Comment: @KevinB: I am using the same code and when I post a request from a client on the same machine I see the OPTIONS part on the server and eventually the request is turned down as "unauthorized" (which makes no sense as far as credentials are concerned), while when I am posting from a client on a different IP, I post the request successfully.

Comment: I guess based on @RayNicholus comment, in the second case, there is no OPTIONS sent to the server and everything works. But then, how can I handle the request correctly in this case in Express? I should change something.

Comment: Simple, you need to handle the OPTIONS/preflight request.

Comment: Well, if I define a route like app.options (aRoute, aHandler); and inside the handler I print a console message that the server is actually executing that part, then, no such message appears on screen

Comment: Then something else in your code/on your server is intercepting the request.  You'll need to look into that.

Comment: I updated the opening post (near the end). Can you suggest some sort of treatment that needs to be done inside the app.options(...) function? Thank you for your time Ray

Comment: I would get rid of the CORS module entirely.  CORS is simple to implement server-side.  No need for a module.  You'll need to acknowledge the Origin, and possibly headers & method of the underlying request in your OPTIONS handler.  Have a look at [the preflighting section of the MDN article on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I will take a look at it. By the way, I am also using basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a problem while calling cross origin resource using ajax from chrome.

I have used node js and local http server to deploy my node js app.

I was getting error response, when i access cross origin resource

I found one solution on that ,

```
    1) I have added below code to my app.js file

        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

    2) In my html page called cross origin resource using $.getJSON();

         $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/users", function (data) {
                alert("*******Success*********");
                   var response=JSON.stringify(data);
                    alert("success="+response);
                    document.getElementById("employeeDetails").value=response;
                });
```

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"` is quite unsafe operation.

Comment: instead of "*" we can restrict user to a particular resource like request with a specific url pattern e.g: locahost:3000/users